# how to add images from Flickr to my website?

Tags: php, image, flickr

I have a photo set on Flickr and want to add images from photo set to my website.

Suppose I have 10 images on Flickr in my photoset. And I want to display 3 images at a time on website from flicker. How will I do this?

Any suggestion?

Comment: check this. it will help you http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several pre-configured Flickr slide shows
http://www.google.com/search?q=flickr+slideshow

You could also use one of the slideshows from this page and put in the individual photo URLs:  http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

If you just want to put 3 Flickr photos in a page, you can use the "Share" button when viewing each photo at Flickr to get a piece of HTML you can then paste into a page. Here's a sample...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>3 Flickr Photos</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/55166285@N00/1274107940/" title="the sunken garden by perfectweb, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1245/1274107940_ede5aa897d_z.jpg" width="640" height="480" alt="the sunken garden"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/55166285@N00/1274119018/" title="tree rings by perfectweb, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1015/1274119018_1422d64d17_z.jpg" width="640" height="480" alt="tree rings"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/55166285@N00/1274114292/" title="study of flowers by perfectweb, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1012/1274114292_f847986865_z.jpg" width="640" height="480" alt="study of flowers"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but they display only one photo at a time and I want three. Look at this url. I want just like this. `http://headlondon.com/our-thoughts`.
You can see the "In pictures" section on the right side. I want exactly like this.

Comment: The page at headlondon.com is a blog, and you are looking at 3 posts with 3 individual photos attached. You could reproduce something similar by just putting 3 URLs to 3 Flickr photos in an HTML page. See edited answer for sample.

Comment: Did your question get answered or do you need more help?

Comment: My question did not get answered yet. I can't put 3 hard code URLs.

Comment: The code I posted has 3 hard coded URLs. Are you looking for something different? Please elaborate.

Comment: yes I want to dynamically and randomly display 3 images from the photo set or an album.